# Copy a file to a folder created with a table field as part of the name

Tags: vba, ms-access

I found some VBA routines here in and I tried to adapt them to my situation.
It works fine but when I try to copy a file to a folder that has been created using in its name a constant “process” and a variable [ID] field, I get an error message.

The error is in this line

FileCopy f.SelectedItems(i), "O:\docs\process\ " & (me.ID)

```
Private Sub Comando356_Click()
' lets say my current record has an ID field value 345
' The routine will check if folder O:\docs\process345 exists
' If the folder does not exist, then the folder is created:

If 
Len(Dir("O:\docs\process" & (Me.ID), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir "O:\docs\process" & (Me.ID)
End If

‘ So far it works perfectly: if the folder does not exist, is created

Dim f As Object
Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
f.AllowMultiSelect = False
If f.Show Then
    For i = 1 To f.SelectedItems.Count
        sFile = Filename(f.SelectedItems(i), sPath)

' My problem is the next line: folder O:\docs\process345 exists but I get an error 76 “Path not Found”       

FileCopy f.SelectedItems(i), "O:\docs\process" & (me.ID)

    Next
End If
End Sub

Public Function Filename(ByVal strPath As String, sPath) As String
    sPath = Left(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\"))
    Filename = Mid(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\") + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Actually it's because you have included a \  in the file copy but not the creation of the directory. So you are trying to copy to O:\docs\process\365  and not O:\docs\process365\

Comment: You are right! That was part of my problem. But If I change the code to FileCopy f.SelectedItems(i), "O:\docs\process" & (me.ID)
Still have an error, this time error 75 Path/file access error

Comment: You then need to add the \ and a file name or *.* . It would help in your debugging if you created the full save path into a string variable and used debug.print to view it in the immediate windows.

Comment: Very confused: 
If in immediate window I print "O:\docs\process" & (me.ID)
It returns exactly what I want: O:\docs\process345
But still have the same error
Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is a folder path, not a document name. You need to copy flibble.doc to `O:\docs\process345\*.*`

Comment: The `Destination` parameter of `FileCopy` must include the file name. Both parameters must be full paths.

Comment: The file I want to copy is f.SelectedItems(i) how do I put that in the destination?

Comment: What does the sFile variable end up holding after you assign it with `Filename(f.SelectedItems(i), sPath)`? Because from what I am seeing, there is never a Set value to `sPath`. It looks like it should come back as `Mid(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\") + 1)`, which should give you the proper file name. If that is the case, you can just use `sFile` for your file reference. So, it would be something like `FileCopy f.SelectedItems(i), "O:\docs\process" & (me.ID) & "\" & sFile` (assuming f.SelectedItems(i) returns the full path and filename)

Comment: Yes @jiggles ! f.SelectedItems(i) returns the full path and filename
Now I can see this clearly. I am trying this first thing in the morning and will post how it goes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes its working perfectly! `FileCopy f.SelectedItems(i), "O:\docs\process" & (me.ID) & "\" & sFile`
I appreciate Everyone's help. So many important details learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a Slash and add the FileName

```
Private Sub Comando356_Click()
' lets say my current record has an ID field value 345
' The routine will check if folder O:\docs\process345 exists
' If the folder does not exist, then the folder is created:

If 
Len(Dir("O:\docs\process" & (Me.ID), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir "O:\docs\process" & (Me.ID)
End If

‘ So far it works perfectly: if the folder does not exist, is created

Dim f As Object
Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
f.AllowMultiSelect = False
If f.Show Then
    For i = 1 To f.SelectedItems.Count
        sFile = Filename(f.SelectedItems(i), sPath)

' My problem is the next line: folder O:\docs\process345 exists but I get an error 76 “Path not Found”       

'   add some debugging
Debug.Print ("in=" & f.SelectedItems(i) & "  out=" &  "O:\docs\process" & (me.ID) & "\" & sFile)
'   add a Slash and add the FileName
FileCopy f.SelectedItems(i), "O:\docs\process" & (me.ID) & "\" & sFile  ' <<<<

    Next
End If
End Sub

Public Function Filename(ByVal strPath As String, sPath) As String
    sPath = Left(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\"))
    Filename = Mid(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\") + 1)
End Function
```